# Regex does not work correctly

Tags: java

I have been using the below pattern matcher to allow mobile numbers in the application only of series +xxxxxxxxxxxxxx(13 digits or more, not any -/?, and restricting alphabets also)

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{3})(\\[-])(\\d{4})$");
```

The above regex is failing the validation. what I am missing.

Comment: "Failing the validation". <- What does this mean?

Comment: First, you have a closing parenthesis without an opening one.. Around `d{3}`

Comment: It is taking all the numbers and special charecters. I want to restrict all the special charecters and charecters as well allowing only + sign and numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

13 digits or more starting with +: sounds like the following would work:

```
Pattern.compile("^\\+\\d{13,}$")
```

Once you've restricted it to be digits, you don't need to worry about "any -/?", because those characters aren't digits.